# integration by part and a limit- Evans PDE Chapt2 problem 13

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations

1) I am having a hard time in seeing how the integration by part done in this problem (page 11)

[enter link description here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~robt/docs/evans_solutions.pdf)

Could anyone help explaining? I cannot see how he got 3 terms instead of 2.
[image]

2. On page 12, I have [image]

I cannot see the first equality leads to the second. In particular the first term vanishes, and there is a term $g(t)$ in the second term.

Comment: Product rule. The first term is the boundary term, and the second two result from the product rule.

Comment: Could you show me how the last two terms result from product rule ?

Comment: many thanks for that!

Comment: I realised there is one more thing I am stuck on. Have edited my question...

Comment: Note for $t=s$ we have some kind of singularity.  Away from $t$ everything is nice, i.e. 

$$
\left|\frac{g(s)x}{\sqrt{4\pi}(t-s)^{3/2})}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4(t-s)}}\right|\leq\max\,|g|\frac{x}{\delta^{3/2}\sqrt{4\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4\delta}}\to 0
$$

as $x\to 0^+$.

(For some reason \max won't say $\max$...)

Comment: but why is the second term disappeared?

Comment: Because of the limit....

Comment: The limit w.r.t. x? I'm sorry I'm still lost...

Comment: Other than w.r.t $x$, there is no other limit. Explicitly,

$$
\left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_0^{t-\delta}\frac{g(s)}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4(t-s)}}\,ds\right|\leq\max |g|\frac{t-\delta}{\delta^{3/2}\sqrt{4\pi}}xe^{\frac{-x^2}{4\delta}}.
$$

What happens to the RHS of the above as $x\to 0^+?$

Also, $g(t)$ should still be inside the integral as $g(s)$ in the first term....

Comment: My confusion is that, I cannot see how the integral inside the absolute value computed in order to be bounded by the things on the right, I tried integration by part but doesn't seem working...thanks for being patient...

Comment: Bound everything inside the integral on the interval $[0,t-\delta]$ and multiply by the measure of the interval (which is $t-\delta$).

Comment: I see what you meant, the integral shall be understood in Lebesgue sense. To clear myself, by any chance you can write what you meant explicitly here?

Comment: also, why is the limit in x of the first term not 0, why can't we do the same $\left| \frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_0^\delta\frac{1}{s^{3/2}}e^{-x^2/4s}ds\right|\leq...$ Is it because we have singularity at $s=0$ so one cannot pass the limit inside the integral?

Comment: We can't bound what is inside the integral on the interval $[0,\delta]$.  What I explicitly mean is written in the above comment.  Everything I've said still holds if the integral is understood in the Riemann sense. For any $f\in C(a,b)$ we have

$$
\left|\int_a^b f\,dx\right|\leq (b-a)\max|f|.
$$

It might help to review a bit of Advanced Calculus before tackling Evans.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me stuff in calculus 2. But why $max|g|$ gives $g(t)$? I thought it is $g(t-\delta)$ for this integral. Also, I do not understand what you meant by "g(t) should still be inside the integral as g(s) in the first term". I would appreciate if this can be shown more explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$
u(x,t)=\int_0^t \frac{g'(s)}{\sqrt{\pi}}(t-s)^{-1/2}\int_x^\infty e^{\frac{-z^2}{4(t-s)}}\,dzds.
$$

Integrating by parts in the variable $s$,

\begin{align}
u(x,t) &= \frac{g(s)}{\sqrt{\pi}}(t-s)^{-1/2}\int_x^\infty e^{\frac{-z^2}{4(t-s)}}\,dzds\Big|_{s=0}^{s=t}-\int_0^tg(s)\frac{d}{ds}\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}(t-s)^{-1/2}\int_x^\infty e^{\frac{-z^2}{4(t-s)}}\,dz\right\}\,ds \\
&= I_1-\int_0^tg(s)\frac{d}{ds}\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}(t-s)^{-1/2}\right\}\int_x^\infty e^{\frac{-z^2}{4(t-s)}}\,dz\,ds \\
&\hspace{20mm}-\int_0^tg(s)\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}(t-s)^{-1/2}\frac{d}{ds}\left\{\int_x^\infty e^{\frac{-z^2}{4(t-s)}}\,dz\right\}\,ds,
\end{align}

where $I_1$ is the notation used in the link.  Computing the derivatives gives the result.